# Firebase Database - prevent writing to all paths other than one specified

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have firebase setup and working (submitting form data clientside) but I was trying to add some rules and validation. There is only one path and it is publicly writable but I wanted to lock it down so no other paths could be created.

I thought I could do:

```
{
 "rules": {
   "myPath": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": true,
     ".validate": "newData.hasChildren([
       'name',
       'email',
       'agreeTerms',
       'results',
     ])",
   "name": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 
   100"},
  "email": {".validate": "newData.isString()"},
  "agreeTerms": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 4"}
  },
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
 }
}
```

This works in the simulator but when I try to submit my form it says access denied.

Can anyone see if I am doing something obvious wrong? All help appreciated.

Oh and the code submitting the data is:

```
const dataBase = firebase.database().ref('/myPath');
dataBase.push(payload, error => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(`Error writing to database ${error}`);
      }
      //worked!!!
});
```

payload is just an object containing the fields from hasChildren.

Payload object that can reproduce the issue:

```
const payload = {
      agreeTerms: 'yes',
      email: 'terry@bingbong.com',
      name: 'Terry Bing',
      results: {
        q1: { score: 0, time: 0 },
        q2: { score: 0, time: 0 },
        q3: { score: 0, time: 0 },
        q4: { score: 0, time: 0 },
        q5: { score: 0, time: 0 },
      },
    };
```

Comment: Can you reproduce with a hardcoded object for the payload? If so, please update your question to show that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I have added that to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `push(...)` which creates a new child nodes under the reference that you call it on. So the properties (`agreeTerms`, `email`, etc) end up under `/myPath/-LK....` and the validation expects them immediately under `/myPath`.

Two possible fixes: use `set(...)` or modify the rules to include the push ID.

The first one is simple:

```
const dataBase = firebase.database().ref('/myPath');
dataBase.set(payload, error => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(`Error writing to database ${error}`);
      }
});
```

Since this calls `set(...)` instead of push, the data is written directly under `myPath` and matches the validation rules.

The second solution is to make your security rules match the code, which means you need to do the validation one level lower in the rules. And since you don't know up-front what the ID generated by `push()` will be, you need to make this a so-called "wildcard rule":

```
{
 "rules": {
   "myPath": {
     "$pushId": {
       ".write": true,
       ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'email', 'agreeTerms', 'results'])",
     "name": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 
   100"},
    "email": {".validate": "newData.isString()"},
    "agreeTerms": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 4"}
    }
  },
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
 }
}
```

In the above: the rules under `$pushId` apply to any child node under `/myPath`. This logic applies to any rules whose name starts with a `$`. So it doesn't have to be called `$pushId`, it could also be `$child` or anything else starting with `$`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great. I'm new to firebase so that has really helped me understand it more.