# Realtime db Security Rules: allow only specific fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say I have a Firebase Realtime database with the below data structure. And let's say I want to allow write access for `uuid` and `content` but not for `locked`. Is that possible to do with the Security Rules?

```
{
  "messages": { 
     "message1": {
        "uuid": "1234",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum",
        "locked": true
     }
  }
}
```

In Firestore you can do something like:

```
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(
  ['uuid', 'content']
)
```

Can the same be achieved for the Realtime Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to only allow specific children, is to allow those children and reject all others. For your example, that'd be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "messages": {
      "$messageid": {
        "uuid": {
          ".validate": true
        },
        "content": {
          ".validate": true
        },
        "locked": {
          ".validate": true
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        },
      }
   }
  }
}
```

This allows writing the named `uuid`, `content` and `locked` properties, and rejects any other properties with a [wildcard capture rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables).

---

If you want to not allow changing the value of `uuid`, you can do that with:

```
"uuid": {
  ".validate": "newData.val() == data.val()
},
```

See the documentation on [new vs existing dat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data)

---

Also see:

- [Firebase realtime database rules to edit only existing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541741/firebase-realtime-database-rules-to-edit-only-existing-fields)
- [Firebase database rules allow update but prevent create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974129/firebase-database-rules-allow-update-but-prevent-create)
- [Firebase Database - prevent writing to all paths other than one specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229106/firebase-database-prevent-writing-to-all-paths-other-than-one-specified)

Comment: Thanks @Frank. However, what I meant was: let's suppose you don't want to allow writing to the `locked` property and only allow reading that property. So, allow reading for all three properties, but allow write only for `uuid` and `content`, but not `locked`. Then `validate` I think would need to be different for read and write. Is that possible?

Comment: That's not what the Firestore rules in your question do, but I added an example of how to prevent changing a specific property value.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I assume "If you want to now allow changing..." in your answer should be "If you want to NOT allow changing..."?